# How to get matrix elements from Image in C#.net?

Tags: c#, .net

I am new to Image Processing. I need to apply the Mean Filter for an image,
so that needs to get the matrix elements in one pixel from an image.

I am getting a pixel value as 2*2 Matrix (ARGB) like `(255,103,103,103)`.
I don't know how to convert the color values `(255,103,103,103)` to an Integer like `25678`
so that I can find the mean value.

Please help me out with the problem.

Answer (score 1):

```
int argb = Color.FromArgb(255,103,103,103).ToArgb();
```